# Link Error: using gcc 4.5.2 on RHEL 6.0 -- I do not understand

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

Here is the command and the error.

```
gcc --shared  \
        -m64 \
        -shared-libgcc \
        -Wl,--whole-archive ./release64/*.a
/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_end' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Did you try closing that linker option (`-Wl,--no-whole-archive` after your `.a` files)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By leaving a "hanging" `--whole-archive` option, you trick GCC into trying to link code compiled without `-fPIC` (from `libc_nonshared.a`) into a shared library. Don't do *that*. Do this instead:

```
gcc -shared ... -Wl,--whole-archive release64/*.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```